# Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses in appstageUrlMatcher.php

Tags: symfony

On my production system i get an error in the symfony router:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation
>   failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 60 in
>   /mypath/app/cache/prod/appprodUrlMatcher.php line 205

Whereas on the local machine and on another server it works fine.

I digged in the cache and the pattern for the route is different:

Working on my dev server:

```
#^/hotels/(?<groupId>[^/\\-]+)\\-(?<groupName>[^\\-]+)$#s
```

Not working on production:

```
#^/hotels(?:/(?<groupId>[^/\\-]+)(?:\\-(?<groupName>[^\\-]+))?)?)?$#s
```

the route is:

```
hotel:
    pattern: /hotels/{groupId}-{groupName}
    defaults: { _controller: "MyBundle:Hotel:hotel", requirements:{ groupName: "[a-zA-Z1-9\+\/]+" } }
```

I read some issues on github that similar errors are possible when using an old PCRE. 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4093
Mine seems new enough thou: PHP 5.3.6 with PCRE Version 8.11.
I am on Solaris.

The patterns are generated by symfony, right? So, why are the patterns different?
And after all why doesnt it work? Has somebody any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a symfony issue but rather a bug in the PHP 5.3.6 version on this Solaris machine.
The constant INF returned *float(0)* which blew up the routing.

See more here: [php INF has value zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667512/php-inf-has-value-zero)