# php INF has value zero

Tags: php

i have a system where the php predefined constant INF var_dumps as 0 (zero).

```
$inf = INF;
var_dump($inf);
```

results:

> float(0)

Is this correct behaviour?
I guess not.

What could have caused that?

This value i would have expected:
http://codepad.org/LQRuFMyg

Comment: Yes, it is. For example, if you do `set_time_limit(0)` this means can be executed infinitely.

Comment: @PLB: No it's not. INF is not zero. And `set_time_limit` doesn't even take a float but an integer. @ivoba: In which PHP version does this happen?

Comment: @ThiefMaster They are not the same but `var_dump(INF)` always outputs `float(INF)` or `float(0)`. I've said that this is correct behavior. and `set_time_limit` was bad example. @ivoba, it will return false.

Comment: on that particular system ```$inf == 0``` is true. on others its false

Comment: @ivoba var_dump `INF` itself. In general that comparison is false. I think, you'd better to report this on php.net

Comment: I have the same problem. On my local linux system `echo(INF == 0 ? " yes " : " no "); ` echo no and on an SunOS Server i got yes. Both systems running PHP in version 5.6.6

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 7.0.0, instead of being undefined and platform-dependent, NaN and Infinity will always be zero when cast to integer.
link：http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php